# Getting WebGLTexture by texture pointer

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, webgl, textures

I'm working on a project using unity WebGL.
What I need to do is to display the game scene in **another browser window**.
So what I tried was I rendered the scene to RenderTexture, and send the texture pointer (from GetNativeTexturePtr()) to the browser side.
When I send the texture pointer I used this jsdll function like:

```
ExtractWindow: function (windowId, w, h, texturePtr) {
    ViewerManager.OnExtractWindow(windowId, w, h, GLctx, GL.textures[texturePtr]);
}
```

I used GL.textures[texturePtr] because I saw it in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html.
I think it's supposed to return the WebGLTexture object, but it's returning null.
This is the only way I know to get WebGLTexture (I'm pretty much beginner in WebGL and Javascript). I'm not even sure if GL.texutre[] is a unity method or WebGL method.
Anybody know how the "GL.texture[]" works? Or is there another way to get a WebGLTexture by texture pointer?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: I don’t know the Unity side but on the webgl side you need to render to a framebuffer - RenderTexture maybe already is one, if you can render to it - bind that framebuffer (gl.bindFramebuffer) and then gl.readPixels. readPixels, and writing them elsewhere, is very slow so I hope this isn’t realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question.
The reason why "GL.textures[texturePtr]" was returning null was because the texturePtr was 0. I found that GetNativeTexturePtr() sometimes works and sometimes just returns 0, I'm not sure why it's working like that. But the workaround I found is to call "colorBuffer" property of the render texture before calling GetNativeTexturePtr(), then it returns the proper ptr.

```
        var cb = _renderTexture.colorBuffer;
        var texId = _renderTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr().ToInt64();
        // texId is not 0 anymore.
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor alone for a RenderTexture doesn't create the underlying hardware object, so the underlying native ptr will be null until something forces it to be created.

Check out https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.Create.html

Try calling _renderTexture.Create() before _renderTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr().

I'm not certain, but trying to access the color buffer on a render texture that hasn't been created yet might create it under the hood.

Cheers